# Effect of switched regulator drop out

Tags: switching-regulator

I am designing a multi-voltage (3, 9, 12, and 15) power supply fed with a 18VAC transformer, about 24.5 peak DC source.  With the toughest requirements, output 15V at 5A, the 6600uf filter capacitors puke out 8% of the time so the 15V,5A load gets nothing from the regulator for about 0.0007sec of a 0.00833sec half cycle.  What is the practical effect of this on the load?  The TPS 54531 regulator has a 3.5 Under Voltage Lock Out (UVLO).  The 94uf output capacitance doesn't last long at 5amps.

Comment: Did you mean to provide a schematic? It's certainly necessary to see what your question is about.

Comment: What does "puke out" mean? What do you mean by "gets nothing"...does the voltage fall to zero? How can we possibly know how the load will be affected if you don't tell us what the load is?

Comment: Puke out means delivering 0 volts and 0 amps.  Only the output capacitance delivers anything to the load.

Comment: A schematic is difficult because of all the extra but necessary components for a switching regulator.

Comment: Where do you get this "puke out 8% of the time" number? Do you have some datasheet for the filter caps you are using? Is this something you observed through testing?

Comment: You want to know how the load will be affected. Then you tell us details about the power supply. You tell us. What is the load?

Comment: see below for my embarrassed apology.

Answer (score 0):

TPS54531 [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/TPS54531) says:-

> To improve drop out, the TPS54531 device is designed to operate at
>   100% duty cycle as long as the BOOT-to-PH pin voltage is greater than
>   2.1 V (typical).

and

> The bootstrap capacitor value must be 0.1 μF.

However it does not say how much current the BOOT pin draws or how long the bootstrap capacitor will take to discharge at 100% duty cycle.

At 5A the internal FET drops ~0.5V, so if the input voltage falls below 15.5V the FET will stay turned on continuously and the bootstrap capacitor won't get recharged. Eventually it will discharge below 2.1V and the FET will turn off, disconnecting the input from the output. This may explain the 0.7ms 'puke out' periods that you are experiencing.

Unfortunately the TPS54531 is not designed to take an external supply voltage on the BOOT pin and the bootstrap capacitance cannot be increased, so the only solution is to keep the input voltage above 15.5V (which should be done anyway to maintain regulation).

Ways to increase minimum rectifier output voltage:-

1. Increase smoothing capacitance.
2. Swap silicon rectifier diodes for high current Schottky types, which have lower voltage drop.
3. Use a transformer with higher output voltage.

Alternatively you could just accept that the power supply cannot deliver 5A at 15V.

> What is the practical effect of this on the load?

That depends on the load. A heater, incandescent lamp or brushed DC motor would be barely affected by the dropouts. LED strips might flicker a bit. An audio amplifier would 'buzz', and a device with sequential logic (eg. microprocessor) might suffer from random lockups or resets.

Comment: A red-faced apology is in order.  I have a Bachelor in Math and I substitute teach at the high school.  A caveat that I tell algebra and calculus students is that more than half of errors made on math tests up through graduate school are not high math but arithmetic, and many of those are simple sign errors.  In my case it's those damn decimal points.  I calculated the drop in the input voltage for a 1/4-cycle (peak AC to zero) using 0.041667 seconds instead of the correct 0.0041667 seconds.  Ergo the regulator does not sut off (puke out) at all. But Bruce's post was extremely helpful.  TNKS.